# How does one load a language file for a 3rd party Joomla extension?

Tags: joomla

The normal way to load a language file located in the admin app is like so:

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
```

And to load a language file from the site app:

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_SITE);
```

These methods load language files from `/administrator/language` and `/language` respectively.

Presently, I need to load a language file from a module that locates its language files at `/modules/mod_foo/language`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, it's as simple as replacing JPATH_SITE with the full path to the module like so:

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('mod_foo', JPATH_SITE.'/modules/mod_foo');
```

This of course assumes that the language file you want to load is located at:

```
/modules/mod_foo/language/xx-XX/xx-XX.mod_foo.ini
```

I had tried this before posting the question, but it didn't work due to a silly typo.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a version or file location difference, but in Joomla3.8.x, Mark Simpson's answered did not work for me with a component. The below did:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$extension = 'com_example';
$base_dir = JPATH_SITE;
$language_tag = 'en-GB';
$reload = true;
$lang->load($'com_example', $base_dir, $language_tag, $reload);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$boolan = $language->load('filename', JPATH_SITE);
```

I tested it with version 3.9.14 and it works because all the languages are in the path language.

The filenames are `com_name, mod_name, lib_name`, or `tpl_name` with language tag at the first part of the filename. The language tags will be added by the load function.

So my component use two language files. `com_name` and `com_name_special`.
`com_name` should be loaded by system but my `com_name_special` needs to be loaded by the extra load function.